# Entries under a channel:categories tag don't show in template group

Tags: channel-entries, url, categories

I am building a personal site to practice with EE, and on my resume page I am using the following code to display a list of categories with entries displayed under each category:

```
{exp:channel:categories channel="resume_skills"}
        <section id="{category_url_title}">
                <h6>{category_name}</h6>
                <ul>
                {exp:channel:entries channel="resume_skills" category="{category_id}"}
                    <li>
                        <p>{title}</p>
                        <p>{description}</p>
                    </li>
                {/exp:channel:entries}
                </ul>
        </section>
{/exp:channel:categories}
```

The page url is /resume (template group), but the entries don't display unless you go to resume/index. The categories display fine however. Any ideas on how I can remedy this and keep the url intact?

I tested it on a separate page (/site/test) to make sure it wasn't anything else in the code on that page messing with it, and it displayed fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try dynamic="no" in your channel tag or you maybe disable strict urls.

Comment: `dynamic="no"` usually solves most things, I can't believe I forgot about that. I had tried the channel:entries as an embed and used it, but never put it back in when I extracted it from the embed. Thanks!